# Is it better to include() or to call functions?

Tags: php, html

I'm currently developing a Web platform app in HTML and PHP stuff. I have to develop a registration/login system, and I'm asking myself a question.

I wrote a login form, and I would like to know if is it better to store it in a php function (with a simple echo("all my login form")) or to store it in a .html file. Obviously, the call or the concerned include() will be written in a if($_session()) statement.

I'm just asking about the correct and logical architecture aspect I should follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're designing something serious i recommend you to use **include** instead of functions. Why?

- the html is separated from php stuff
- cleaner, highlighted html files in web editors
- you avoid once and for all those double quotes/escapes and such
- you give designers a way to change your file at will; a designer will not touch PHPs.
- easier to update files; think templates
- an include() can still go onto a function if you insist :)

Answer (score 1):

You should put in a .html file, it's always better to separate your applications logic and presentation code.

Also, consider using a [template engine](https://www.google.com/search?q=php%20template%20engine&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aunofficial&client=firefox-nightly&channel=fflb).

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, and regardless of language, an `include` should never have side effects other than importing variables and functions into the current scope.

Hence if you do use an `include`, it should contain a function that *when called* produces output.  The mere act of calling `include` should not generate any output.

Comment: Is this also correct for an include() on a .html file ? Because I just want to include a login form, just some basic html code.

Answer (score 1):

Include would "include" new code every time it is called. The normal way is to define a function in a php file and require it, before you use it anywhere with require_once, so you would only load the functiondefinition once and could use it everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to include in most cases but it depends on how big the file is that u have called

well calling functions again and again each time you wont even like .

well in one of cases u can call a function if its short and not called on other pages

but if u want to implement a logic everywhere like check login ,logout then include is the way to go .

Comment: I'll use the `include` only for the header and the footer I guess. My login form will only be called into the homepage.

Comment: well for example you can write all your function in a single php file (common.php) which has all the logic . and you can just call the function on any page .foe example you can print an array or declare post variables .

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use include()  for your registration system by which you can get a function just by calling it and you don't have to create it at any other pages .just include it and all work is done.this method reduce the redundancy problem and make you code short & simple.

Comment: Are you talking about an include() on a .html file or a .php ? But I'm talking about include a .html file with the login form html code, not a .php file. My question is only about storing the login Form (only html code) into an echo into a php function (which I'll include later..) or directly in a .html

Answer (score 0):

I use include() but tend to name the files blah.template.php instead of .html.

Then, within the template, I can use simple looping, variable substitution, and simple if-else statements.

If the project is larger, I use a minimal templating class that wraps the call to include().  This class, among other things, wraps the call with ob_start() and ob_get_clean() (I think those are the calls) and allows getting the template's output as a string.

Also, for repetitive bits of HTML code, I think it's legit to use "picture functions" that return the HTML code.  Picture functions allow you to parameterize the code and add some logic.